# Why won't Ubuntu Software Center let me edit my review?

Tags: software-center

So I've just recently decided to try out MonoDevelop for other things after writing a review a while back about .pyproj files not being supported...

turns out, I'm unable to edit my review for it to mention it's lack of support and broken features as well as being outdated.

I wanted to rate it 2 stars as it's about as good as using Visual Studio w/o any advanced features.

but my 4-star review I made earlier has no edit or delete option, and of course I'm not allowed to submit another review...

http://lh3.ggpht.com/-AExx14cOyWk/VGzTbaWBmQI/AAAAAAAAIBs/CNfoK5yKZMU/s800/Screenshot%2520from%25202014-11-19%252012%253A26%253A16.png

what's going on here, and why won't it let me edit??

Answer (score 1):

Editing is not a feature of reviews. Reviews are not the place to report problems with software, either.

If the software is broken in some way, you should file a bug against it. You can run `ubuntu-bug monodevelop` to file a bug against MonoDevelop, for example.

Comment: I just said, I want to rate it with 2 stars, not 4. With a good reason as to why. (I never said anything about reporting a bug)